# Numpy: division by zero error, but mathematically function is apparently defined

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm testing out some functions to fit with data, and one of them (in 2-D) is

```
f(x) = (1/(1-x)) / (1 + 1/(1-x))
```

Which, according to [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+1%2F(1-x)+%2F+(1+%2B+1%2F(1-x))) and the [Google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Pb3uXM7KEvLuxgPDzJuICQ&q=1+%2F+%281+-+x%29+%2F+%281+%2B+1+%2F+%281-x%29%29&oq=1+%2F+%281+-+x%29+%2F+%281+%2B+1+%2F+%281-x%29%29&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30j0i8i30l5.293090.304078..304793...5.0..2.421.10842.2-7j25j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39j0i67j0i131j0j38j0i22i30j33i22i29i30j0i5i30.ocZN9RdCrhk) plotters, gives you the result

```
f(1) = 1
```

I've tried to get this to work without hard coding the case

```
if x == 1:
    return 1
```

but I end up with a `nan` and a `RunTimeWarning` informing me that I have indeed divided by zero.

```py
import numpy as np


def f(x):
    return 1/(1-x) / (1 + 1/(1-x))


x_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = f(x_range)
print(y)
```

Is there a more elegant solution than to simply introduce a hard-coded `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason to keep it in this form, you can simplify it to:

```
def f(x):
    return 1/(2-x)
```

Wolfram and Google probably to some sort of algebraic simplification too.

Comment: Fair enough, that's probably the best solution.
Let's assume that I kept it in the "broken" form, just for interest sake.

Comment: In that case, one other way to avoid hard coding the x=1 case is to plot instead x_range = np.linspace(0, 1 - 10**-6, 50) ?

Comment: That's also an interesting workaround, actually that was my go-to solution before I came and asked this question. Anyway, I've adapted my model based on your suggestions. The real thing is in 3-D, and when I look at too many variables at once, it seems that I lose the basics. Good to know that a fresh pair of eyes can easily sort out this kind of thing!

Answer (score 0):

Just simplify the equation for f(x) = (1/(1-x)) / (1 + 1/(1-x)). The simplified equation will be (1/(2-x)). Now update the program as:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x):
    return 1/(2-x)
x_range = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = f(x_range)
print(y)
```

output:

```
[0.5        0.50515464 0.51041667 0.51578947 0.5212766  0.52688172
 0.5326087  0.53846154 0.54444444 0.5505618  0.55681818 0.56321839
 0.56976744 0.57647059 0.58333333 0.59036145 0.59756098 0.60493827
 0.6125     0.62025316 0.62820513 0.63636364 0.64473684 0.65333333
 0.66216216 0.67123288 0.68055556 0.69014085 0.7        0.71014493
 0.72058824 0.73134328 0.74242424 0.75384615 0.765625   0.77777778
 0.79032258 0.80327869 0.81666667 0.83050847 0.84482759 0.85964912
 0.875      0.89090909 0.90740741 0.9245283  0.94230769 0.96078431
 0.98       1.        ]
```